# Arranging nested directives in parent template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm building a directive named card. I want to use it like this:

```
<card theme="light">
    <card-header>
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
    </card-header>
    <card-options>
        <button class="btn btn-default">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger">
            <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
        </button>
    </card-options>
    <!-- more will be added later, such as card-body -->
</card>
```

When that compiles, I'd like it to produce this DOM:

```
<div class="card card-light">
    <!-- cardHeader class uses flexbox and is expecting
         only two child elements -->
    <div class="cardHeader">
        <!-- this div is the first child and should contain the header -->
        <div>
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
        </div>

        <!-- this div is the second child and should contain the options -->
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
            </button>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Card template:

```
<div class="card card-{{cardVM.theme}}" ng-transclude>
</div>
```

Card header template:

```
<div class="cardHeader">
    <!-- Header goes here -->
    <div ng-transclude></div>

    <!-- Options go here... but how? -->
    <div></div>
</div>
```

I suspect I may have to pass the cardOptions element up to the parent card, and then bind to it from within the cardHeader?

```
<div class="cardHeader">
    <!-- Header goes here -->
    <div ng-transclude></div>

    <!-- Options go here -->
    <div>
        {{$parent.optionsElem}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure that would work, and if it did, it seems cumbersome and inefficient.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 5th parameter of `link` function is the `transclude` function, allowing you to manually transclude the contents of the element hosting your directive.

`ng-transclude` is really a shortcut for the following behavior:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transcludeFn){
   transcludeFn(function(clonedContents){
      element.append(clonedContents);
   }
}
```

It transcludes the entire content, linking it to the outer scope, and places it inside the `ng-transclude` element.

So, in your case, using `ng-transclude` would not work. Instead, you'd need to manually transclude and identify which part to put where. It helps if you use placeholder elements in your template:

```
.directive("card", function(){
  return {
    transclude: true,
    scope: {...},
    // simplified template for illustrative purposes:
    template: '<div>\
                 <div class="header">\
                    <card-header-placeholder></card-header-placeholder>\
                 </div>\
                 <div class="body">\
                    <card-body-placeholder></card-body-placeholder>\
                 </div>\
               </div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transcludeFn){
       transcludeFn(function(clone){
          var root = angular.element("<root>").append(clone);
          element.find("card-header-placeholder")
                 .replaceWith(root.find("card-header"));

          element.find("card-body-placeholder")
                 .replaceWith(root.find("card-body");
       });
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: FWIW, clone was an array of elements, so I had to use clone.filter instead of clone.find.

Comment: @mbursill, fair enough - `filter` could work, but I typically add a root element: `var root = angular.element("<div>").append(clone)` and then `root.find("div")` (I edited the question)